# Change text inside a span has duplicate id using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have two tags a div

```
<div id="en">..</div>
```

and a span of same id

```
<span id="en">..</span>
```

i want to change text only on span

```
$('#en').text("sometext");
```

but not in div is there any way to specify it uniquely? like this

```
$('span#en').text(obj.en);
```

Comment: Attribute *id* must be unique in a document, use *class* instead....

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute should be unique and duplicate id isn't valid in html.

However you can use attribute selector

```js
$('span[id="en"]').text("sometext");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="en">div</div>
<span id="en">span</span>
```